# ML model deployment with flask does not work

Tags: python, flask

i want to create one simple  project based on iris dataset, which will  allows user to enter data on website and make  a prediction on web ,here is code (which consist of 3 steps), first  step is actual  model creation and converting to pickl format :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle

# Load the csv file
df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

print(df.head())

# Select independent and dependent variable
X = df[["Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", "Petal_Length", "Petal_Width"]]
y = df["Class"]

# Split the dataset into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=50)

# Feature scaling
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test= sc.transform(X_test)

# Instantiate the model
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()

# Fit the model
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make pickle file of our model
pickle.dump(classifier, open("model.pkl", "wb"))
```

it works fine,next one is  web model format -which allows user to enter data from web :called as index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!--From https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/EGdtg-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ML API</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
</head>

<body>
 <div class="login">
    <h1>Flower Class Prediction</h1>

     <!-- Main Input For Receiving Query to our ML -->
    <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Sepal_Length" placeholder="Sepal_Length" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="Sepal_Width" placeholder="Sepal_Width" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="Petal_Length" placeholder="Petal_Length" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="Petal_Width" placeholder="Petal_Width" required="required" />

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict</button>
    </form>

   <br>
   <br>
   {{ prediction_text }}

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

if we run on  browser, it shows such result :
[image]

and finnaly code which  actually connects model to  web form

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

# Create flask app
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))

@flask_app.route("/")
def Home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@flask_app.route("/predict", methods = ["POST"])
def predict():
    float_features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    features = [np.array(float_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(features)
    return render_template("index.html", prediction_text = "The flower species is {}".format(prediction))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

if i run this file, i get :

```
* Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 111-250-705
```

if  i go to   http://127.0.0.1:5000, then i am getting

```
TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

but index.html is in the same directory, so  please help me to fix this issue